# Wordpress - Gravity Forms - 307 on POST

Tags: wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin, http-status-code-307

I have a gravity form in 2 steps.

When going to the next step, in some countries, they get a 307 status back on the POST, so the next step doesn't load and you are stuck on a spinning wheel.

In my country, this is not a problem.
In the country where this happens, it happens on different WIFI's, so not only with 1 person.

Anyone has an idea what the problem could be?
There are no country restrictions and have no clue why some get a temporary redirect..